# Remove Decimal of Price in Admin and Front End

Tags: magento-2.1, magento-2.1.3

I want remove the decimal in product price in admin and front end

**Admin:**
[image]

**Front-End**
[image]
I tried to modify `price-utils.js` under this path
\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\base\web\js

in line 38:

```
precision = 0
```

But it still didn't work. Is there an extension like `ET Currency Manager` for Magento 2.1.3 or are there other ways to remove all the decimal?